# Unit testing: try statement in program.cs Main

Tags: c#, testing, program-entry-point, xunit

I have my project that starts like below. I want to create a unit test to validate what happens when either `appsetting.Environment.json` doesn't exist or the `DataSource:JsonPath` file doesn't exist.

I am using xUnit but just getting into it,

With this scenario it should throw a `FileNotFoundException` and exit.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

        try
        {
            Log.Information($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Starting...");

            var jsonFileName = Configuration["DataSource:JsonPath"];
            if (!File.Exists(jsonFileName)) throw new FileNotFoundException(jsonFileName);

            //code if file exist...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does you unit test method look like? What problem do you face exactly?

Comment: Btw, your Main method will not throw any exception. If you already are into unit tests, you should already have the basic C# knowledge to see this... ;-)

Comment: I simply just don't know where to start with this, it might be because it is in the Main that it confuses me.  ***Elgonzo, since there is an !File.Exist it does indeed throw new exception and gets in the catch not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: So did you try writing a unit test? I see no evidence of one here. Where's your unit test method, with its Arrange, Act, Assert?

Comment: @KaptainJ, i was not talking about the File.Exist method, i was talking about the Main method. (i.e., something like `try { Program.Main(...); } catch(Exception ex) {...}` will never catch anything, because there is nothing to catch)

Comment: You are right I am not clear.  What I want to test and make sure is the behavior of the main method with a problem with the json file and validate that the if !file.exists do what it needs to do

Comment: That's not a unit test... This is an integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing any of your code, there are two ways to do this:

- Actually run the program using the [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and examine the exit code of your program (exposed in the [`Process.ExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property). In this case, the fact that the class is `internal` and the `Main` is `private` doesn't matter.
- Use reflection to get ahold of the `Main` method and invoke it, examining the return value.

If none of those are palatable, you can change your `Main` to `internal` and use the [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute to enable your unit test to call that method without reflection.

For all 3 of these cases your test passes if the exit code is 0 and fails if the exit code is 2 (assuming there are no other possible exit codes).

Answer (score 0):

Under the best circumstances you would have `Log` dependency injected into `Main` or whatever class you are trying to test.  Then you would test that your `Log` methods were called under whatever circumstances you developed.  You would also have your Configuration and File Access dependency injected instead of being tightly coupled so you don't have to actually do real read/write access on physical media to test your code.  As it stands you can not do *real unit code testing* because you have tightly coupled external dependencies, so you code is technically doing integration testing.

I would suggest reading [Autofac DI container in console app](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56197/autofac-di-container-in-console-app).  (I don't have any affiliate with [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), I just prefer it over other DI frameworks.  There are many so do some research if you decide to use them).  If I were to implement it, it might look something like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
      var container = CreateContainer();
      var worker = container.resolve<IWorker>();
      worker.Execute();
    }

}

internal class Worker : IWorker
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    private IFileSystem _filesystem;
    private ILog _log;
    private IDateTimeFactory _datetimeFactory;

    public Worker(
      IConfiguration configuration,
      IFileSystem filesystem,
      ILog log,
      IDateTimeFactory _datetimeFactory)
    {
      _configuration = configuration;
      _filesystem = filesystem;
      _log = log;
      _datetimeFactory = datetimeFactory;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            _log.Information($"{_datetimeFactory.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Starting...");

            var jsonFileName = _configuration["DataSource:JsonPath"];
            if (!_filesystem.Exists(jsonFileName)) 
              throw new FileNotFoundException(jsonFileName);

            //code if file exist...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Fatal(ex, "Terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            _log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}
```

The following is a general example, I cannot guarantee it's 100% working.
Now when I want to test the worker, I can literally test anything:
(I'll assume you want to test using [nSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) and [nUnit](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnit-Documentation))

```
[TestFixture]
public WorkerTests
{
  [Test]
  public void Execute_ConfigurationFileNotFound_LogsException()
  {
     var config = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();
     var filesystem = Substitute.For<IFileSystem>();
     var log = Substitute.For<ILog>();
     var datetime = Substitute.For<IConfiIDateTimeFactory>();

     var worker = new Worker(
       config,
       filesystem,
       log,
       datetime)

     // setup the mock'd file system to always return false for Exists()
     // That is what we're testing
     filesystem.Exists(string.Empty).ReturnsForAnyArgs(false);

     worker.Execute();

     Assert.That(log.Received().Fatal(), Is.True);
  }
}
```